# Could not find gem error on vagrant-vmware-workstation installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vmware-workstation

I am trying to install vagrant -vmware workstation on my machine. But I am getting following error

```
Could not find gem 'c:/Users/Automation1/Downloads/license.lic (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

I tried with version 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2 and 2.2.3 but always get same error

Here is full installation log text

```
Installing the 'vagrant-vmware-workstation' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Installed the plugin 'vagrant-vmware-workstation (4.0.1)'!
Installing the 'c:/Users/Automation1/Downloads/license.lic' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Bundler, the underlying system Vagrant uses to install plugins,
reported an error. The error is shown below. These errors are usually
caused by misconfigured plugin installations or transient network
issues. The error from Bundler is:

Could not find gem 'c:/Users/Automation1/Downloads/license.lic (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more
than once without a block is a security risk, and may result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come
 from the secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.Warning: this Gemfile contains multiple primary sources. Using `source` more than once without a block is a security risk, and may
 result in installing unexpected gems. To resolve this warning, use a block to indicate which gems should come from the
secondary source. To upgrade this warning to an error, run `bundle config disable_multisource true`.
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you shure you're using the right command.

I had the same problem with following command

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-workstation  path/to/license.lic`

but it works with:

`vagrant plugin license vagrant-vmware-workstation path/to/license.lic`